# Why is the version of libatlas on Ubuntu so old?

Tags: package-management

The versions of libatlas available on [Debian](http://packages.debian.org/sid/libatlas-base-dev) and/or [Fedora](http://rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/epel/5/i386/atlas-sse2-3.8.3-1.el5.i386.html) are much more up to date (as in more than a year if not two newer) than those I see in the Ubuntu repositories.

1. Why that is?
2. Is it possible (advised?) to bypass the Ubuntu repos and use the packages from the Debian reps (and run into dependency hell)? Or is there a fundamental reasons why libatlas is stuck at 3.6.X in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

libatlas in Ubuntu 10.10 is at upstream version 3.8.3, the same as in Debian and Fedora. See:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/libatlas-base-dev

Your best bet is to upgrade to 10.10 (which will be released in two days at the time of this post). Backporting lib packages from Debian or Ubuntu development releases can be a tricky proposition as you would likely have to rebuild any of libatlas' reverse dependencies against the new version as well.

Comment: Ok thanks (i didn't know a more recent release of Atlas was included in 1010).

Answer (score 1):

[libatlas](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/i386/libatlas-base-dev) is in the [Universe](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu) repository. According to the Ubuntu Help:

> - **Universe** - Community maintained software, i.e. not officially supported software.

This software may not be high priority for the maintainer. You should [file a bug or ask a question](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/atlas) to the libatlas maintainer, and see if they will consider upgrading the package.

It appears that Ubuntu 10.10 (Maverick Meerkat) will include [ATLAS 3.8.3-22ubuntu2](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/atlas#packages_list) . Ubuntu 10.10 will be released this month, although you should consider waiting a few weeks or more to let others shake out the bugs in 10.10.

You also might be better off installing ATLAS from source, instead of relying on the Debian or Ubuntu maintainers.

Comment: You can also try your hand at packaging (Especially if this is an important package for you) and possibly take over the maintainers role for this package.

Comment: Hi Marco. I don't think i'm qualified for packaging or managing. Specially this is a pretty low level package. I'm happily using it but i've no idea how it works.

Comment: Hi Stefan:> I'm okay with installing things in ububtu, but Atlas is in a league of it's own (the install guide is over 30 pages long and includes such oddities as switching CPU cores off ect...)